# Forward Kinematics for a Robot Arm with an offset

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

Hi I am working with a WidowX-200 robot arm. I have an fake joint between joints 2 and 3 to simulate an offset in the actual robot arm.
[image]

The joints are motors which can turn and here are the joint angles I have defined:
[image]

Here are my DH parameters:

[image]

I have tried forward kinematics, but am getting strange results especially in relation to the fake axis. Are my DH parameters correct?